# CakePHP 3 : dynamically create options in select | Form Helper

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers, cakephp-3.2

I want to generate `select` input field like

```
<select name="quantity">
  <option value="">Quantity</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

where option is generated dynamically.

There is a `stock` column which contains int value. I want to generate options as much as value in stock. Ex: If `stock` value is 5 then option will be from `1` to `5`.

I can generate select input field by

```
$this->Form->select('quantity', [1,2,3,4,5], ['empty' => 'Quantity'])
```

But here options generated will of 5 length. I want it to be generated as per the value in `stock` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First set your $stack variable value in controller using set**
(Simple way) :

```
 $this->set('stack', $stack);
```

**use that variable like this in your view:**

```
$options = range(1,$stack);

 $this->Form->select('dropdown name', $options, ['empty' => 'Quantity'])
```

Comment: Thanks @pradeep, but there is a problem here... value assigned are from 0 onwards like `<option value="0">1</option>` I want to assign value from 1 `<option value="1">1</option>`

Comment: use this  > $options = range(0,$stack);   unset($options[0]); then use $options

Answer (score 1):

you can use php [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function

```
$options = array_combine(range(1, $stock), range(1, $stock));

$this->Form->select('quantity', $options, ['empty' => 'Quantity'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=[];
for($i = 0;$i<$stock;i++) array_push($arr, $i); 

$this->Form->select('quantity', $arr, ['empty' => 'Quantity'])
```